# Rendering a mp4 file in angular4 from amazon-s3 send through springboot application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am doing a demo , for streaming video using angular5  . The video is stored as inputstream in amazon s3 and it is returned as streaming response.

Here's the code for that :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFile")
public StreamingResponseBody getObject() throws IOException {
    ObjectListing objectListing = amazonS3.listObjects(bucket);
    for (S3ObjectSummary os : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
        System.out.println(os.getKey());
    }
    S3Object s3object = amazonS3.getObject(bucket, "fileIcon");
    S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();
    return (os) -> {
        readAndWrite(inputStream, os);
    };
}

private void readAndWrite(final InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {

    byte[] data = new byte[123456];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = is.read(data)) > 0) {
        os.write(data, 0, read);
    }
    os.flush();
}
```

**But I don't know how to display it using angular5 . can anyone help.**